# Which hard disk encryption is in use?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

how can I find out, which hard disk encryption is used on my machine? When I boot, it says: Please unlock disk nvme0n1p3_crypt. I have the password, but the computer was set up by someone else and I don't have a lot of experience with Ubuntu.

Comment: Sounds like this is Luks encryption and is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively to pLumo's answer, another way is to open the Disks app if you are not CLI only. Select your main disk and you will see one split in half in the Volumes section.

[image]

In Contents section under that graph you can see some information, such as LUKS for myself. It may or may not be the same for other types encyptions, but LUKS is very popular.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's it! I have a LUKS encryption, like pLUMO assumed.

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
blkid
```

This will show you the type of the partition. In your case it probably shows `TYPE="crypto_LUKS"`, meaning the disk encryption type is `LUKS`.

If you don't know which partition to look at, check output of

```
lsblk /
```

---

[See also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108537/verify-if-a-hard-drive-is-encrypted-on-linux).

Comment: When i run this command, it gives me three lines with three different types: 
LVM2_member, swap, ext4

Comment: I just found out its LUKS, your guess was correct!